# Why is an Array seen as Object in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, array-filter

I know this questions has been asked quite some time now, but this behavior is really weird.

I have an Array of Objects (fetched from my Realm Database) with the following structure:

`userDates = [{aT: [array], id: "..", ...}, {aT: [array], id: "..", ...}, ...]`

I want to filter this array like the following:

`const filtered = userDates.filter(x => x.aT.includes("2022-03-01"))`

It says "x.aT.includes is not a function".
If I run this:

`const filtered = userDates.filter(x => console.log(x.aT))`

it will print out:

```
["2022-03-01", "2022-03-02","2022-03-03"]
["2022-03-13", "2022-03-14","2022-03-15", "2022-03-16"]
["2022-04-01", "2022-04-02","2022-04-03"]
```

"typeof" says: "object" and "Array.isArray" says "false".
I'm confused. x.aT is obviously an array.

Comment: Can you show how the structure in your question is fetched with Realm, so we have a better understanding of what they actually are?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a Realm List? https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.List.html

Comment: Arrays are objects btw. But because a Realm list is iterable you can probably do `Array.from(x.aT).includes`

Comment: Also console.log never really tells the truth. Especially in React, there's a lot that goes on under the hood to try and make the logs more digestable and less spammy.

Comment: I think the data wich you are fetching is in json format. If it is first try to JSON.parse() it to get the decoded Object then access and filter that data.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. ```Array.from(x.aT).includes```actually solved it! It is weird that even if it seems to be an obvious array, it still handles it differently. Thank you @windowsill

Comment: If you want to know more search "array-like objects" in js. They are really common object structures with length and iterable properties.